# Running same sync process on local db VS Asure

Tags: sql-server, performance, wcf, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a WCF service on azure which perform multiple tasks.

**Tasks:**
1. download a file from a remote server (about 50MB)
2. preform bulk insert to a Azure Database (about 360,000 records) at once.
3. run 2 different SP (about 15 sec tops both)

The total process takes about 1 min on my local SQL server 2012 Database,
but when I try to run it from a cloud WCF (not Cloud Service) it takes more than the timeout connection can handle (4-30 min).
Still I don't understand why there is a significant difference of performance.

Cloud Resources? and if so how can I make it perform better same as if I ran it locally (as close as I can)?

Regards,
Avishai

Comment: What type of Azure Database are you using? You likely local DB on a better hardware specs than the Azure database, and hence it Azure database runs slower.

Comment: Yes Jan may be right. In azure you ve got a limitation on Data Throughput Units. It sets the number of transactions /seconds. The more you pay, the more DTU you have. So have a look on Azure SQL subscription. You can change for the length of a test it to test whether it 's faster

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelDURIN, you are right increasing the DTU's made it faster (end more expansive :)), but still the connection idle timeout is set to default (4 min), and now I need to increase it to 15 minutes..

Comment: Set-AzurePublicIP : Cannot bind parameter 'VM'. Cannot convert the" Instance name>" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.IPersistentVM". At line:1 char:52 + Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName  <PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS>    -VM "<Instance name>" -IdleTimeoutInMi ... +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~   + CategoryInfo     : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzurePublicIP], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.Se tAzurePublicIPCommand